# Как перехватить траффик сокетов между двумя приложениями

Tags: websocket, сокеты, трафик

На машине стоит программа, которая запускает Хром, подключается к нему по сокету (т.е. получает т.н. EndPoint и подключается к этому EndPoint-у) и начинает им управлять.
Вопрос: какой программой можно посмотреть трафик между управляющей программой и Хромом?
Пробовал tcpview от SysInternals  - но не увидел в ней этого трафика.
Может быть я что то не так понимаю в сокетах

Comment: Открой инспектор хрома.

Comment: Мысль хорошая. Но devtools в запускаемом хроме отключен

Comment: Почему бы не включить его?

Comment: Хром можно запустить с отключенным девтулс без возможности включения. Что и делает управляющий софт

Comment: Это он делает параметры командной строки скорее всего. Найди в софте где это и  hex редактором поменяй букву в этом параметре и тогда хром пропустит это.

Comment: Я нашел файл, в котором прописан этот параметр. HEX редактором поменял одну букву "o" на "a" и приложение перестало работать)) Дело в том что есть главный exe файл, который запускает  другие файлы. В одном из этих других прописан параметр командной строки, который отключает devtools. Подозреваю, что в момент запуска проверяется контрольная сумма (хеш) всех дополнительных библиотек. Поэтому приложение перестает запускаться.

Comment: Если продолжать эту мысль - то нужно научиться включать devtools на хроме, на котором он был отключен параметром командной строки.

Answer (score 0):

Обычное решение для прослужки хрома это включить keylog

В окружение пользователя добавь:

```
SSLKEYLOGFILE=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\sslkey.log
```

В Wireshark

Перейди в меню [ Edit > Preferences > Protocols > TLS ]. В параметре (Pre)-Master-Secret log filename укажи путь к этому файлу.

Потом запускаешь на интерфейс any и ищешь пакет этой программы (сверься с netstat). Скорее всего соединение установлено на нестандартном порту - поэтому  правой кнопкой на этом пакете - декодировать как TLS.

Не так удобно как devtools.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но пока что ничто из предложенного не полетело)

Comment: Я написал похожую программу, которая запускает Хром, и посылает ему всяческие команды. И вот трафик своей программы я вижу и WireShark, и в TcpView и netstat /a показывает открытый порт 9999. И в WireShark я прямо вижу что я посылаю Хрому. А из трафика этой программы я вижу только трафик Хрома, который что то посылает на IP-шники Гугла. Т.е. трафик с хостом 127,0,0,1 отсутствует (в WireShark я смотрю "Adapter for loopback traffic capture") .  Сделал по твоей инструкции - в файл лога ничего не пишется.

Comment: По идее - используются вебсокеты. И на примере моей программы WireShark в поле "Тип протокола" так и показывает "WebSocket".

Comment: а точно ли вэбсокеты используются? адаптер any есть?

Comment: Насчет вебсокетов я уже не уверен. С одной стороны - я вижу библиотеку Chrome-Launcher, которая запускает Хром. И она по идее формирует EndPoint... С другой стороны - трафика я не вижу.

Comment: Адаптер Any - где его смотреть?

Comment: Приложение написано на фреймворке Electron (NodeJS фреймворк)

Comment: электрон это не хром...

Comment: Электрон - это фреймворк, который позволяет создавать Windows-приложение на JavaScript. В данном случае - это робот, который управляет установленным на машине Хромом

Comment: electron это браузер с одной вкладкой на основе хромиума, это не сам хром. у электрона есть апи взаимодейсвия js программы - js вкладки..

Comment: Ты привел один из вариантов использования электрона. Также ты можешь запустить обычный Хром, установленный на твоей машине, подключиться к нему и управлять этим обычным Хромом. Что и делает этот робот. Но при этом он с помощью параметров строки отключает расширения, девтулс и многое другое. Но то что это тот же самый Хром, который стоит у меня на машине - не сомневайся. Если зайти в "О программе" - там будет идентичная версия.

Comment: Наверное, если как то научиться отслеживать абсолютно весь трафик конкретного приложения - это бы наверное помогло. WireShark это не показывает

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй включить в переменные окружения REMOTE_DEBUGGING_PORT=9222. Если запускалка не чистит окружение, то тогда к хрому можно будет подключиться с другого хрома.